# WebSphere Application Migration Toolkit (v20.0.0.1) not installing on Eclipse 2019-12 IDE for JavaEE Developers

Tags: eclipse, migration, websphere-liberty

I'm currently having a problem installing the latest version of the WebSphere Application Migration Toolkit (v20.0.0.1) to Eclipse 2019-12 IDE for JavaEE Developers. I'm receiving the following message when trying to install:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>
> Software being installed: Oracle to WebSphere Application Migration Tool 3.21.0.v20200305_1150 (com.ibm.ws.appconversion_feature.oracle.feature.group 3.21.0.v20200305_1150)
>
> Missing requirement: Application Migration Tool - Common Feature 3.23.0.v20200305_1150 (com.ibm.ws.appconversion_feature.common.feature.group 3.23.0.v20200305_1150) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.birt.feature.group 2.3.2' but it could not be found
>
> Cannot satisfy dependency: 
>   From: Oracle to WebSphere Application Migration Tool 3.21.0.v20200305_1150 (com.ibm.ws.appconversion_feature.oracle.feature.group 3.21.0.v20200305_1150)
>   To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.ibm.ws.appconversion_feature.common.feature.group 3.17.0

Answer (score 1):

The error shows up because one of the WebSphere Application Migration Toolkit dependencies, BIRT, is missing from the latest Eclipse versions. You'll need to install BIRT separately. In Eclipse, go to Help -> Install New Software. In the Work With field, paste in the Eclipse 2019-09 URL: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-09. Select the Business Intelligence, Reporting and Charting and go through the installation steps. Restart Eclipse and try to install the WebSphere Application Migration Toolkit again.